# Filtering power supply noise

Tags: power-supply, noise

I am getting 7 volts from a power supply source which I need to step down to 3.3 V for powering up my 2.4 GHz zigbee MCU (TI CC2530 + CC2592 amplifier).

I am using a linear regulator to step it down. My schematic is as shown below:

[image: linear regulator]

Randomly I am seeing MCU resets and brief communication failures. I checked the power line waveforms and they look like these (with ac coupling):

Input (7 V line):

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

FFT looks like this:

[image: 3]

Output (3.3 V line)

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

FFT looks like this:

[image: 3]

I can do nothing about the input. What should I do to ensure a better power line for the MCU in order to get rid of resets and communication failures.

Note - same circuit works fine if I power it up from my bench power supply.

EDIT (solution posted below):

I followed @analog's solution but with different values (because I didn't have the values that he mentioned):

[image: cktt]

Setup:

[image: setup]

Waveforms with 180 ohm load on the 7 V line (ac coupling):

[image]

[image]

Waveforms with 33 ohm load on the 7 V line (First one is DC coupling and rest are ac coupling):

[image]

[image]

[image]

EDIT: Adding more waveforms.

Both probes connected at Vout. Tested at no load and 33 ohm load conditions. Yellow line is DC coupling. Blue line is ac coupling. No load voltage is roughly 7.5 volts. At 33 ohm load, the voltage drops down to roughly 5.7 volts.:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How much current are you drawing from the linear regulator?

Comment: The regulator datasheet recommends a 22uF solid tantalum on the output for stability (and that probably means there is a minimum ESR). Have you tried that?

Comment: You have your noise filtering caps, but that looks like your input voltage is dropping below the point your linear regulator can handle? I think you need to add more capacitance to the output.

Comment: I have tried adding 100 uf electrolytic with 0.1 uf ceramic on output, input and both. Didn't help much.

Comment: Long shot at this low frequency, but show your probe setup.

Comment: The LDO cannot filter out high-frequency trash. You must do that. Insert 10 (TEN) ohm resistor between your +7v source and your circuit. And consider adding more input capacitance. And use a Ground plane. And avoid sharing Vias between input-side caps and output-side caps.

Comment: Oh, it was not a long shot. Your probe setup in totally inadequate for measuring high frequency noise. Look up Dave @ EEVBlog, he has a YouTube tutorial on the subject. Also, your “layout” isn’t helping either.

Comment: @winny - I will check the video for sure. However on a side note, the schematic suggested by analog appears to be helping. Am I missing something?

Comment: It sure should. You will however fool yourself in terms of absolute numbers for your ripple unless you have adequate probing. The relative improvement you will however catch. Here is the video: https://youtu.be/Edel3eduRj4 Fast forward to 18:47 if you don’t want to watch the whole thing.

Comment: Pretty much what I thought, you have no PCB and hence no layout, so it's not going to work properly. At least you should get breadboard so you can keep things tight and have a decent strip of copper for power/GND.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxPRrp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If your current demand will not allow the 10 ohm resistor, then use 1uH inductor in parallel with 100 ohms Rdampen.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it. Hopefully it fixes my problem.

Comment: I didn't have the exact component values that you suggested. I used different values for a proof of concept and it worked. Thanks a lot man. How can I buy you a beer?

Comment: How clean is the output? Set scope on 1 microsecond/division, ACcouple, 10 millivolt/division, have only one scope probe in use with its ground clipped onto the right(quiet) end of the Ground Plane.

Comment: I will be able to do that after 13 hours from now. Will post the image for sure. Till then can you please help me understand the impact on my output when I replace 1.5 mH with 1 uH. I will be reducing the inductance by a factor of 1500. What can I do to compensate for this? Will changing 5 ohms to 10 ohms (R1 as per your ckt) improve the performance?

Comment: examining your photos, I see very slow ramps which the LDO should be able to servo-out (regulate-out, remove). I also see ringing at frequency near 4MegaHertz, which LDOs have trouble with. The 10 ohm resistor and 100uF cap form a 1 millisecond time constant, which is 1/(2 * pi * 0.001) = 160Hertz. Given the ground plane, to help the big-cap be more effective, you ideally would see 4,000,000 / 160 = 24,000X attenuation. But caps have ESR that limits the high-frequency attenuation. The inductor helps at high frequencies. Use 1uH or  10uH (or any inductance in that range). No magic here.

Comment: I edited the schematic, added another RC filter after the (optional) input inductor. How much load current will the clean-circuits need? if more than 20 or 50mA, the voltage  drops across these 3.3 and 10 ohm resistors may reduce the LDO input voltage below what the LDO needs (over temperature etc) to be able to regulate.

Comment: I need 50 mA regular and 150 mA during zigbee transmits but I guess that can be provided by the caps.

Comment: Assume 7vraw, and 4.5v to the LDO so it always can regulate. If 2.5v/15 ohms, the 0.15 amp peak draw is OK. Just keep any inductor resistance to < 0.5 ohms. Trying to ensure you are successful here, so am conservative.

Comment: I'll be able to perform some tests in 3 hours. Thanks a lot for your help. I will post my test results soon. You haven't answered the question about the beer :)

Comment: I posted the waveforms. Please take a look and advise. Thanks

Comment: I tried shorting the 1.5 mH inductor and the waveforms didn't change much. Looks like RC filter is doing the heavylifting here.

Comment: Another update - 7V filtering looks good so i broke the pcb trace of VIN and inserted this filter before LDO. However, my 3.3 V line was still noisy - even more noisy than the unfiltered 7 V line. There are UART lines going to the voltage source as well and the GND plane covers the entire PCB and shared by each and every element (Vin, Vout, MCU, source etc). I will modify my PCB, keeping the Vin and GND of input caps separate from GND of MCU. I am also considering putting some resistor in series on the UART lines (100-1000 ohms). Do you suggest a similar RC filter for UART?

Comment: Where is your scope probe GROUND connected?

Answer (score 1):

You've got extremely low switching speed in the PSU, 350µs works out to about 2.9kHz, it should generate a clearly audible whine at such a low speed. It might be caused by low load power saving feature kicking in, we don't know what the current drain is.

The output is ringing at about 2MHz (0.5µs). I'd hazard that the problem here is your wiring/PCB, try adding 4.7µF ceramic caps right next to both IC power pins. 100nF is not very effective at 2MHz, depending on the package it'd be around 0.5-1R.

Comment: The output caps that you see in my voltage regulator circuit is placed quite close to the pins of zigbee. Trace length = 15 mm. Trace width = 10 mils (0.254 mm)

Comment: I tried adding load on the 3.3 V line. 43 ohms resistor. Didn't help. I added 22 uF electrolytic + 0.1 uF ceramic on 7 V line and 100 uF electrolytic + 0.1 uF ceramic on the 3.3 V line. Still the waveform didn't change much. I replaced the linear regulator with a different part number (linear again). Still no difference.

Comment: Unless you got a low-z electrolytic, 22µF can's ESR will be quite high. And even with "low" impedance cans it's around 1R at 100kHz. Generally speaking, you'd need something like 220µF can to have a significant impact on switching noise and the "low" impedance would be in the ballpark of 0.2R or so. You'll definitely get more mileage out of your 4.7µF ceramic capacitor. Do you have a proper GND plane? You could try adding a small RC filter in the IC power feed e.g. 1R and 4.7µF would suppress the 2MHz noise to ~1/50th or 34dB attenuation.

Comment: I will check the RC filter and revert back. I tried 470 uF electrolytic. It reduced the noise a bit but not up to satisfactory levels.

Comment: I tried 680 uf on input and 680 uf on output. No change. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @whiskeyjack Adding 680µF to LDO input doesn't change the sawtooth pattern? That seems unlikely. In any case that 4.7µF ceramic still has low-er impedance (~20mR) than your 680µF electrolytic even if it's high ripple current Low ESR type. And those are big. Are you connecting the oscilloscope GND probe directly to the LDO GND pin? There are many things that can go wrong powering circuits, it's not possible to debug without seeing actual layout and schematic and that's maybe a bit beyond the scope here. The basic rule is to connect IC power and gnd pins to bypass caps with minimal traces <3mm.

Comment: If you don't have GND/VCC planes in your PCB, you should route/connect power/gnd to the capacitor pad 1st and pull another trace from the capacitor pad to the power/gnd pin. It's a good idea even if you do have dedicated power planes.

Comment: It's night time here. I will post the updates tomorrow including my measurement setup. I hope I am doing something dumb which gets rectified asap. BTW I am using a GND plane and the PCB is approx 40 mm X 40 mm. I have added multiple GND vias at random locations as well.